# How to create a display for n events in Android Studio?

Tags: android, layout, calendar, view

I'm building an Android app which displays events for a certain period of time. I have the data stored in a Google sheet which I'm using as a database, and I've got no problem pulling that data in as JSON (using Google's API). However, I'm now thinking of how to display this data.

I'd like to display it in a similiar manner to how BBC displays news articles: Many identical layouts which have been inflated n times, which I can then populate with my data. I'm wondering how to do this? Could someone point me in the right direction? You don't need to write any code or anything (if you do, much appreciated!). I just need to know what to look up.

Cheers

[image: Screenshot of BBC app]

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the View Pager with TabIndicator
http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

For the tabs section 
And Look out for recyclerview and card view for listing the items

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

Comment: thanks a bunch! That's exactly what I was looking for. So sorry I made you search for tab views; I wasn't looking to do that.